# Getting an "X-frame-options is set to Deny" when I don't have the setting in my web.config

Tags: iframe, iis-7, x-frame-options

We have an IIS7 website page that is accessed via a third-party website through an iframe. It's been working fine up until a few days ago with the following error from Chrome:

> Refused to display 'https://xxxxxxxx' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Edge reports a slightly different error, but in essence, it reports not being able to access fonts on that target website.

Now I've checked the `web.config` file and there is no custom header with the 'x-frame-options' set anywhere, but we do have the 'x-xss-protection' header that is set to '1; mode=block'. I've tried removing the block

`X-XSS-Protection 1;`

but then I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

I also remove the entire x-xss header entirely, which takes me back to the original message. I then manually add in

```
X-Frame-Options Allow-From https://xxxxxx
```

> Refused to display 'https://xxxxxx' in a frame because it set multiple
>   'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, allow-from
>   https://xxxxxx'). Falling back to 'deny'.

Any ideas where the x-frame-options Deny is coming from? I've loaded web.config into an editor and it definitely does not find that header in there.

Courtesy of Lex Li, I have turned on Failed Request Tracing and have found this in the logs:

[image]

But where is it referencing the x-frame-options from? The Set-Cookie header is also not existing in my web.config, so it must be elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: HTTP headers can be set at multiple places, so you cannot merely focus on IIS. Enable FRT to see if your web app generates the deny header, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: The page that loaded by iframe returned this error. So have you checked whether the application inself are adding this header? Open your failed request tracing in IE then you will see the formatted report. Besides, did you upgrade your chrome?

Comment: The application - you mean the origin or the target application? I'm using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I mean the web application 'https://xxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by uninstalling Windows update KB4532931, not sure exactly of the details as the description of the .net vulnerability from MS is generic (remote execution).

Answer (score 0):

We also had this same error on an IIS7 website page that is accessed via a third-party website through an iframe. We traced the issue back to patch KB4532931 being applied to the web server. Rolling back that patch fixed the problem. We are currently looking for a more permanent solution.